# JavaScript isn't working in my Thymeleaf template

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a Thymeleaf template and a js file, I did import the js file but it isn't working.
My pages load, and my backend starts without any errors but I cant get the javascript functions to work.

Here is my Thymeleaf template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http/www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <div th:replace="template :: header"></div>
    <title>Cenovnici</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div th:insert="template :: navbar"></div>
    <div class="table">
      <h1 align="center">Cenovnici</h1>
      <div class="row col-md-12 table-responsive">
        <table class="table" width="52%" border="1" align="center">
          <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#ffe4c4">
              <th>Datum vazenja od</th>
              <th>Poslovni partner</th>
              <th>Detalji</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <div>
              <tr
                th:each="cenovnik, rowStat: ${cenovnici}"
                th:style="${rowStat.even} ? 'color: gray' : 'color: white;'"
                bgcolor="#ffe4c4"
              >
                <td th:text="${cenovnik.pocetakRokaTrajanja}">
                  Datum vazenja od
                </td>
                <td
                  th:text="${cenovnik.poslovniPartner.nazivPoslovnogPartnera}"
                >
                  Poslovni partner
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    th:href="@{'/cenovnik/detalji/' + ${cenovnik.id}}"
                    role="button"
                    >Detalji</a
                  >
                </td>
              </tr>
            </div>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <a
          class="btn btn-primary"
          th:href="@{/cenovnici/dodavanje}"
          role="button"
          >Dodaj cenovnik</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div th:replace="template :: scriptFrag"></div>
    <script src="../static/js/stavkeCenovnika.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the js file with some logic defined in it:

```
$("#addStavkaCenovnika").click(function (e) {
  $("#addModal").modal("show");
  $("#confirmSave").on("click", function (e) {
    var cena = $("#cena").val();
    var roba = $("#roba").val();

    var cenovnikid = $(".cenovnikId").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/stavkeCenovnika",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        cenovnikId: cenovnikid,
        cena: cena,
        robaId: roba,
      },
      complete: function (data) {
        window.location.reload();
      },
    });
    $("#addModal").modal("hide");
  });
});
```

Here is the project structure image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place jquery script `<script src="jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>` in the body and always put your javascript after third party scripts